# Is this definition of a Fuchsian operator correct?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-equations, differential-operators, d-modules

In Bjork, *Analytic D-modules and applications*, the following definition of a Fuchsian operator is given:

[image]

Here, I believe, $D(0)=\mathcal{O}$, the zeroth filtered piece of the ring of germs of differential operators at $0$, i.e. the ring of regular functions at $0$ (the alternative interpretation of $D(0)$ of the stalk of $D$ at $0$ does not make much sense I think, since then the $\alpha_i$ would completely mess up the form of the differential operator written above).

Now according to this definition, the operator
$$P=(t-e)\partial_t-a = \frac{t-e}{t}\Big(t\partial_t-\frac{t}{t-e}a\Big),$$
where $e$ is some non-zero complex number, is not Fuchsian, since $(t-e)/t\not\in \mathcal{O}$. However, in "D-modules, perverse sheaves, and representation theory", the following fragment, I believe, is also supposed to serve as a definition of a Fuchsian operator:

[image]

The operator $P$ does satisfy the equivalent conditions of this theorem. In fact, point *(iii)* of this theorem makes it clear that if $Q$ is Fuchsian, then so is $g(t)Q$, for any rational function $g(t)$. This invariance under rescaling by a rational function is not satisfied by the definition in Bjork, so the two are clearly not the same.

So my question is, is this a misprint in Bjork? Or is Bjork using some alternative notion of Fuchsian operators, and if so, why?